# Jackson XML parsing, two wrappers have the same child element

Tags: jackson-databind

My XML is a workflow exported from Jira. It looks like this:

```
<workflow>
    <initial-actions>
        <action>...</action>
        <action>...</action>
    </initial-actions>
    <global-actions>
        <action>...</action>
        <action>...</action>
    </global-actions>
</workflow>
```

Trying to parse it into a POJO, I have Workflow class defined like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "workflow")
public class Workflow implements XMLDocumentHeader {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "initial-actions")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "action")
    private List<Action> initialActions = new ArrayList<>();
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "global-actions")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "action")
    private List<Action> globalActions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But that is not allowed because I have the localName "action" associated with two setters:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "action"
```

But if I omit `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "action")`, then when I serialize the POJO, the output will be incorrect:

```
<initial-actions>
    <initialActions>            
    </initialActions>
</initial-actions>
<global-actions>
    <globalActions>
    </globalActions>
</global-actions>
```

I have `@JacksonXMLRootElement(localName = "action")` for the Action class too, but it doesn't do anything.

How can I have two `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` with the same `@JacksonXMLProperty(localName)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding Actions class.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class Actions {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "action")
    private List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then use `Actions` instead of `List<Action>` in Workflow:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "initial-actions")
private Actions initialActions;
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "global-actions")
private Actions globalActions;
```